# Python 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I am crawling a particular url from google.com but i get some error

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 72: invalid continuation byte
```

Code:

```
import re
import os
import MySQLdb
import codecs
import requests
import base64
import random
import gzip
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import datetime
import time

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
def proxy_mesh():
    while True:
        try: 

            data = requests.get('google.com')

            print data.text.encode('utf-8')
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            print "Trying again"
            time.sleep(3)
proxy_mesh()
```

What is the FIX and how to over come this error?

Comment: In other words, you're trying to decode using `utf-8` while the encoding was done differently.

Comment: Can you give the traceback? This could be occurring implicitly in several places.

Comment: @Mounarajan as suggested in the link I provided, you need to use different encoding. Can't tell you which one without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple and it works.  The data has already been decoded by the `requests` module.

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=http://N%E2%94%9CO-RESPONDER@MERCAOLIVRE.COM&outputFormat=json')
print data.text
```

Since it is a JSON response, you may also want to process it:

```
import json
print json.loads(data.text)
```